# Use Matlab with GUI on remote server via VNC

Tags: ssh, x11, gui, vnc, matlab

I might have a too basic question. I'm trying to use Matlab on a remote server with the standard Matlab GUI. (The GUI is quite essential for development, e.g. for debugging; and I really need to do the development on the remote server as I need to access very large files.) For now, I'm using X11 forwarding via ssh, but that is very sluggish, and I gathered from [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932806/is-it-possible-to-run-matlab-on-a-remote-server-and-control-it-using-the-matlab/34358711#34358711) that VNC might be a good alternative.

Also, somehow after some time, when I try to plot in Matlab, the new X window popping up for a Matlab figure window is completely blank and errors are thrown in the Matlab Command Window. Then I have to not only close Matlab, but even exit the ssh session and log back by running `ssh -X` ... Really inconvenient.

The owner of the server requires me to use a Yubikey to generate a one time password (OTP), and to tunnel the connection through `ssh`. In fact, the standard VNC port(s) is (are?) blocked on the server. So, this is what I have done:

1. Setup a VNC session on the remote server by running:

   ```
   vncserver :0
   ```
2. Create an `ssh` tunnel by running on my local machine in the Terminal window of OSX:

   ```
   ssh -p4022 -N -L localhost:5901:localhost:5900 my_user_name@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   ```

   where the `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is standing for the server's IP address. I have to use my Yubikey here and then enter my user password on the server.
3. Run the VNC client on my local machine executing the following in Terminal:

   ```
   open vnc://localhost:5901
   ```

   I need to provide the VNC pw here that I created the first time of doing the above under point 1.

My experience at this point is that I seemingly managed to connect to the VNC session running on the server, but I can see only a blank screen.

Why can I not see a GUI of the operating system and then go away and start Matlab - this is what I would do on my own Raspberry pi. Probably this is where my lack of experience with Linux makes me stuck.

Is there actually not a GUI available by default? I tried to run `startx` on the server, but probably nothing happened. The output in the Terminal was the following among others:

```
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Is there a way to start an x application, Matlab or any other, and direct it to a particular VNC desktop? It would be really useful if I didn't need to close the Matlab session on the remote server every time I want to close the X window on my local machine, but I could log back to the same remote VNC desktop.

Any comments would be really appreciated. Probably I need something really step-by-step and exact.

Thank you in advance!

Tamas

**Edit**: Thanks for the comments. In the meantime, I have realised that a Gnome desktop is actually installed on the server. Therefore, according to [this note](https://www.its.hku.hk/faq/research/hpc/software/how-use-vnc-launch-remote-x-windows-pc) I added the last line to my ~/.vnc/xstartup now reading in full as:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
gnome-session &
```

However, this has not solved the problem. Actually, running `gnome-session` is not successful, just as running `startx` wasn't. I get the following thrown

```
...

xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

So, it looks like the Gnome desktop installation needs to be troubleshot first by our IT staff.

Otherwise, [this question on stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129432/vnc-server-without-x-window-system) suggests only a desktop can be relayed by VNC.

Comment: What VNC server are you using? there's usually a distinction to be made between standalone VNC (`vnc4server`,`tightvncserver` et al.) and "desktop sharing" VNC servers such as `x11vnc` or `Vino` that are intended to provide remote access to a physical X display

Comment: Hello, I believe i'm using this linux application: https://linux.die.net/man/1/vncserver

Comment: There is no physical display for the remote server, I believe. It is a high-performance computing server used by many users. Perhaps it's running headless. I found 'vncviewer' in the bin directory. Perhaps it's similar to 'vnc4viewer'. Perhaps this is exactly the software what is to be used on a headless server, if I understand you correctly. Would you please give some instructions if 'vncserver' can be made work with my setup?

Comment: Ah my mistake - I assumed when you mentioned *"a GUI of the operating system"* you were referring to an existing local display - please ignore my previous comment

Comment: Did you set up a `~/.vnc/xstartup` file on the remote server? if so, please [edit] your question to include its contents.

Comment: Could it be that i have the black VNC client screen because no GUI desktop is present on the headless server? I cannot install a desktop, like it is described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7, as I'm not a sudo-er. Therefore, I wonder if VNC can be used also without a GUI desktop.

Comment: It shouldn't matter that a desktop isn't *running* on the remote server, but some of the software components (such as a basic window manager) will need to be installed (which they likely are, if `vncserver` is).